# Set datetime variable with milliseconds

Tags: vb.net, datetime, milliseconds, date-conversion

I need to set a datetime variable with milliseconds in VB.NET, I'm trying to convert using:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

But the result is, for example:

> 2017-07-26 11:47:45 AM

I used a string variable to convert the `Datetime.Now()` but before convert to datetime I lost the milliseconds precision.

How can I store milliseconds in a datetime variable in VB.NET?

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? Why are you converting a `DateTime` into a `String`, just to get it into a `DateTime` again? It's a nonsense

Comment: All datetime types include milliseconds.  The real problem would seem to be displaying them?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to set a vb.net datetime variable a full datetime expression. If I use a string variable to do it, the result is Ok but, before convert this string to datetime, I lost the millisecond precision

Answer (score 1):

Milliseconds require the use of `ttt`:

```
.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ttt")
```

On a totally separate note, if you just do **`DateTime.Now`** then you **have the milliseconds already** - no need whatsoever to convert to a string and then parse again...!